# Easy way to amend all commits in unmerged feature branch?

Tags: git

Is there a fast way to undo all commits in a feature branch (keeping the changes unstaged) and quickly do some loops of `git add -p` and `git commit` to create a new cleaner history when you know how you can group changes in hindsight?

So let's say I have 80 commits on a huge feature of which some commits are reverts of things called "temp save" (yes I could have stashed it, but I didn't).

So I only want to undo all commits of the feature branch. I know for example I can `git reset HEAD^N`, can I do the same but with `master/HEAD` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is just [reset with "mixed"-option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). So if you have your feature branch active and you want to remove the commits and still retain the changes and start fresh from master-branch:

```
git reset --mixed master
```

Then you can do the commits you see fit.

Comment: So actually all this time I was searching for something I thought was complex but in fact it is just `git reset origin/master` because `--mixed` is default and I would like to re-add everything that changed from the current master. Funny

Comment: @ThomasMoors Yes I also read from the documentation that --mixed is indeed the default, but I still left it here for clarity. In this business, I'm glad that sometimes the simplest solution is enough :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do a `rebase` in interactive mode.

The following command shows you the commit history, to be edited.

```
git rebase -i <earlier SHA>
```

Then:

- `pick` commits you would like to keep,
- `reword` the commits for which you would like to edit the commit messages
- use `squash` and `fixup` to combine commits
- delete lines to 'undo' changes from commits you want to forget about.

For more details, c.f. the section "mass undo/redo" in this great article:[How to undo (almost) anything with Git](https://blog.github.com/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/) .

Comment: This could be a solution for many cases, but mine has the problem that some commits are that bad that squash-ing and reword-ing isn't going to cut it. Still +1 because for normal rebasing this is just the solution.